# Remove phrase from some elements in pandas data frame

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame which I am trying to remove a phrase from the front of some  elements:

Sector

1. Industrial Engineering
2. FTSE All-Share Sector Real Estate
3. FTSE ST All-Share
4. FTSE All-Share Sector Industrial Transportation
5. FTSE All-Share Sector Fixed Line Telecommunications
6. FTSE All-Share Sector Software & Computer Services

So when the element starts with 'FTSE All-Share Sector ' I would like that phrase removed to leave

Sector

1. Industrial Engineering
2. Real Estate
3. FTSE ST All-Share
4. Industrial Transportation
5. Fixed Line Telecommunications
6. Software & Computer Services

I have tried

```
df.Sector = df.Sector.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('FTSE All-Share Sector '))
```

which works in some instances, but not in others

1. List item
2. Industrial Engineering
3. Real Estate
4. {*Blank*}          ie all content is removed
5. Industrial Transportation
6. ixed Line Telecommunications
7. ftware & Computer Services

So I guess it is working on each character in 'FTSE All-Share Sector' not as words

I have also tried

```
df.Sector.replace (["FTSE All-Share Sector "],[""])
```

which runs but has no discernible effect

and

```
if df.Sector.str.startswith('FTSE All-Share Sector '):
    df.Sector = df.Sector[-24:]
```

which generates the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Alan\Downloads\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.2.1.201401262345\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 466, in __get_module_from_str
mod = __import__(modname)
File "C:/Users/Alan/workspace/Data analysis/Tests\import.py", line 57, in <module>
if df.Sector.str.startswith('FTSE All-Share Sector '):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 665, in __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
ERROR: Module: import could not be imported (file: C:\Users\Alan\workspace\Data analysis\Tests\import.py).
```

Thanks in advance, hoping its a simple fix!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.replace.html):

```
df.Sector = df.Sector.str.replace ("FTSE All-Share Sector ", "")
```